# I could not retrive values sent by controller in view file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.When I perform add function I need to calculate tax. I have tax value in a table I need to fetch the value from the table and use it in my view page.

```
 public function view()
        {
            $this->load->library('session');
            $data['service_detail']=$this->session->userdata('service_detail');
            $data['tax'] = $this->settings_model->get_tax();  
            $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service/view';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data); 
        }
```

In model file I have this function by which I get the tax value from the table

```
public function get_tax()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT company_tax13 FROM service_settings ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Here is my view file where i get the tax value.

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Service price: <?=$service_detail['service_price']?> Rs</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Tax Percentage : <?=$tax['company_tax13']?>%
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php 
     $tax_percentage=$tax['company_tax13'];
    if(strstr($service_detail['service_tax'],"inclusive")==true) {
    $taxamount=$service_detail['service_price']-($service_detail['service_price']/(1+($tax_percentage/100)));
    $grand=$service_detail['service_price'];
    }
    else {
    $taxamount=($service_detail['service_price']*(1+($tax_percentage/100)))-$service_detail['service_price'];
    $grand=$taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
    }
    ?>
    <label for="email">Tax Amount : <?php echo $taxamount; ?> Rs</label>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Grand Amount : <?php echo $grand; ?> Rs</label>
    </div>
```

I could not get the tax value in my page. 
Can someone help me. I do not know the reason why i get no value in my output.

**Edit 01**

In `service_detail['service_price']` contains either inclusive or exclusive. with that value I use strstr() to compare that string.

Comment: just change `$query->result_array();` to `$query->row_array();` in model file. Or use foreach loop inside your view to get data

Comment: I got the value but it happens only for inclusive.. what may be the reason

Comment: else {
    $taxamount=($service_detail['service_price']*(1+($tax_percentage/100)))-$service_detail['service_price'];
    $grand=$taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
    }This does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_array()` instead of `result_array()` because `result_array()` returns the first value in index 0 and you should call:

`$tax[0]['company_tax13'];`

Comment: yes it works.. but still few more doubts now it works for inclusive but not for exclusive... What may be the reason

Comment: @anu what do you mean by inclusive and exclusive. please update your question and describe it.

Comment: @Anu It's another question and I should know what is in service_detail session. `$this->session->userdata('service_detail');`. use `=='true'` instead of `==true`.If it doesn't solve your problem ask it as a new question & let me know.

Comment: $this->session->userdata('service_detail') is a array that contains the service price and tax type. service price is a number and it works fine for me. but tax is a string. Using that i need to calculate tax

Comment: Does it have any string like 'inclusive' in it? read strstr() doc. http://php.net/strstr It doesn't return true. It returns anything after 'inclusive'. For example $string = 'inclusive123'; $a = strstr($string, 'inclusive'); The variable $a is 123

Comment: if you want to see if 'inclusive' is in your string or not then you can use `preg_match('/inclusive/', $string);` it returns true if the word is in the string and false if not.

Comment: why? it can be easily done with preg_match if it is a part of the string and if it is the whole, then you can compare whole words like if('a' == 'a') :-s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82908/discussion-between-meh-and-anu).